# How is an 'App' different from any regular (native?) application?

Tags: windows

Is "app" just a term that refers to a family of tiny, light-weight mobile-device-centric applications -- a trend that started with the Apple i-generation of devices and later found its way to Android and Windows 8?

If the same program were available both as an app and as an application for the same platform, what difference does it make to the system running it? For instance, Angry Birds for Windows is available as :

- [Angry Birds app for Windows 8/RT](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-us/app/angry-birds-space/8ece2571-91e0-4f2f-b7e5-b0b7944ced2d) and [Angry Birds app for Windows 7 (runs on Pokki)](https://www.pokki.com/app/Angry%20Birds)

  versus
- [Angry Birds for PC](http://shop.angrybirds.com/us/angry-birds-pc-version.html)

From a developer's perspective, are the above two just the same code compiled differently to produce binaries suitable to the target?

Also, now that platforms like Mac(iOS/OSX) and Windows 8 are common to mobile computers as well as desktops, is the line distinguising apps from native applications being blurred?

**UPDATE:** 
I'm not questioning the choice of the word usage as in [Appropriate use of “app” vs “application”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/45762/28634). This question has more to do with how apps differ from native applications in terms of memory footprint, resource utilization, dependence of execution subject to presence of runtime environments on the client machine etc.

**UPDATE 2:**
Microsoft is encouraging [Windows developers to build apps for Windows 8](http://www.windowsstore.com/developers/windows). Apart from additionally having to adhere to [Windows Store app guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770552), how is what they build different from what they've been building all along?

Answer (score 0):

App is just short for application. On some platforms the abbreviated name seems to have stuck... There is no technical meaning other than "application for this platform".

On windows 8 the new style programs are built differently from "desktop" applications. (They really have to sort out the names, metro apps at least gave you a name for it...). It's not just the same program rebuild for a different platform as the methods of interfacing with the system is a bit different. There is a new runtime library and a much more restricted runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 is different than Windows 7 and previous OSs because it has some additional features that developers can use to make their apps more alluring for the users, features like:
1. charms  - settings, search, share
2. snap view 
3. concept of store apps
4. new design language for store apps
5. Live tiles etc.

Windows 8.1 is different than Windows 8 because it essentially provides an update to the W8 features, for example:
1. roaming settings
2. Hero search
3. snap view - split the screen into any size
4. concept of universal app development

Windows 10 is different than windows 8.1 in a more stronger sense so to speak because a lot has changed, such as:
1. Concept of app targeting to single UAP
2. new XAML controls
3. cortana
4. action center
5. inking

Hope this helps.